# Compile section of large document while maintaining numbering

Tags: numbering, compiling

I have a large document, and to minimize compilation time, I would like to recompile only the last section of it as it is edited.  My trouble with standard solutions is that they destroy the numbering: I would like theorems, definitions, etc. in the final section to be numbered as they would in the entire document, rather than starting at 1.

Is there a standard solution for this?  Ideally, I'm hoping for an environment that works like a comment except that it adjusts counters.  For example, it would have the following behavior:

> \begin{specialenvironment}
>
> \begin{theorem} This theorem will not show up at all. \end{theorem}
>
> \end{specialenvironment}
>
> \begin{theorem} This will show up as Theorem 2. \end{theorem}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\include` and `\includeonly` macros are for this, where each `\include` is the name of a file that makes up a portion of the document. Briefly

```
% MWE.tex
\documentclass{article}
\includeonly{lastsection}
\begin{document}
\include{mostsections}
\include{lastsection}
\end{document}
```

where `mostsections.tex` is a file containing all but the last section and `lastsection.tex` is a file containing the last section. If you compile `MWE` without the `\includeonly` you will get the complete document. If you then compile it with the `\includeonly` you will just get the last section typeset with all numbering correct. Edit `lastsection.tex` and recompile you will get a revised last section with all numbering correct. If there is an `\includeonly` LaTeX will only process the listed files, ignoring everything else, but retaining the overall numbering system.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great.  Small detail for posterity: it seems you need to compile the entire document first (without the includeonly line), and then add in the includeonly for a secondary compile, and it works from then on.